# What are these wide-flat-headed screws called?

Tags: screws

Please can someone advise what is the correct name for these screws? I went to a local DIY store but couldn't seem to get them.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [sheet metal screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw#Types_of_screw_and_bolt) with a Phillips head.

It is very similar to a flange-head screw and somewhat similar to a pan-head screw.

Comment: Screws with a built in washer head are often called *cabinet screws* (at least in the US).

Comment: "Truss-head" I would say. An odd use of the word truss, but it's a thing.